# VBA UserForm label in spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a problem with running the UserForm I have created. I have 5 labels in my UserForm, but when I run the UserForm to get the input for the excel spreadsheet, my labels do not show, only dates, numbers etc. that I have put into the text boxes and comboboxes. Deso anyone know the solution to this problem?

```
Private Sub btncalculate_Click()
  txtactualprofit = txtincome - txtexpenses   
End Sub

Private Sub btncancel_Click()
    Unload Me    
End Sub

Private Sub btnreset_Click()
    Unload UserForm1
    UserForm1.Show        
End Sub

Private Sub btnsubmit_Click()    
    Dim emptyRow As Long

    'Make Sheet2 active
    Sheet2.Activate

    'Determine emptyRow
    emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 2

    'Transfer information
    Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = cmbmonth.Value & "/" & cmbyear.Value
    Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = txtincome.Value
    Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = txtexpenses.Value
    Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = txtactualprofit.Value
    Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = txtbudgetedprofit.Value         
End Sub

Private Sub monthandyear_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
  MsgBox "Month & Year"    
End Sub

Private Sub sbexpenses_Change()
  txtexpenses.Text = sbexpenses.Value
End Sub

Private Sub sbincome_Change()
  txtincome.Text = sbincome.Value  
End Sub

Private Sub txtexpenses_Change() 
  Dim NewVal As Double

  NewVal = val(txtexpenses.Text)
  If NewVal >= sbexpenses.min And _
     NewVal <= sbexpenses.max Then sbexpenses.Value = NewVal    
End Sub

Private Sub txtincome_Change()   
  Dim NewVal As Double

  NewVal = val(txtincome.Text)
  If NewVal >= sbincome.min And _
     NewVal <= sbincome.max Then sbincome.Value = NewVal
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()    
  'Empty Income Text Box and Set the Cursor
    txtincome.Value = ""
    txtincome.SetFocus

  'Empty all other text box fields
  txtexpenses.Value = ""
  txtactualprofit.Value = ""
  txtbudgetedprofit.Value = ""

  'Clear All Month and Year Related Fields
  cmbmonth.Clear
  cmbyear.Clear

  'Fill Month Drop Down box - Takes Jan to Dec
  With cmbmonth
    .AddItem "JAN"
    .AddItem "FEB"
    .AddItem "MAR"
    .AddItem "APR"
    .AddItem "MAY"
    .AddItem "JUN"
    .AddItem "JUL"
    .AddItem "AUG"
    .AddItem "SEP"
    .AddItem "OCT"
    .AddItem "NOV"
    .AddItem "DEC"
  End With

  'Fill Year Drop Down box - Takes 2010 to 2018
 With cmbyear
    .AddItem "2010"
    .AddItem "2011"
    .AddItem "2012"
    .AddItem "2013"
    .AddItem "2014"
    .AddItem "2015"
    .AddItem "2016"
    .AddItem "2017"
    .AddItem "2018"
 End With
```

End Sub

[image: UserForm]

[image: Run and submit UserForm]

[image: Excel spreadsheet]

Comment: So you have a label on a `UserForm` but when you initialize it the label does not show? Can you provide a screenshot. Actually 2 screenshots - one with the userform in Development mode and one after the `UserForm` is initialized with the non showing labels?

Comment: I have added the code in my question. New to this, so not the fastest. I will provide screenshots in a minute.

Comment: I have also added screenshots, let me know if it is the right or wrong pictures!

Comment: so what happens when you click ` btnsubmit`?

Comment: It sumbits everything into the sheet (the numbers I have inputed), except the label names

Comment: So (a) what does the UserForm input look like and (b) what output is appearing in Excel?

Comment: I have added the code, and screenshots to the question. That should show it

Comment: Do I understand your correctly: You want the labels next to the text and combo-boxes to appear in the first row of your spreadsheet, as column headers? And currently you have absolutely no code for that, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have the labels text on your worksheet, before this code:

```
'Transfer information
Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = cmbmonth.Value & "/" & cmbyear.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = txtincome.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = txtexpenses.Value
```

Write:

```
Cells(1, 1) = Label1 'Change Label1 to the actual label name
Cells(1, 2) = Label2
Cells(1, 3) = Label3
Cells(1, 4) = Label4
Cells(1, 5) = Label5
```

And change `Label1` to the actual name of the label.